# group objects in the category of groups and Eckmann–Hilton argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be the category of groups and $G\in \mathscr C$. Let
$$m:G\times G \to G,e:1\to G, i:G\to G$$
be associated morphisms satisfying the commutativity diagrams.

I wonder whether it is true that the binary operation $\otimes$ induced by $m$ is necessarily the binary operation $\circ$ given by the definition of group $G$.

To show this, I am considering using the Eckmann–Hilton argument, but I don't know how to show (and now I am not even sure) that 
$$(a \otimes b) \circ (c \otimes d) = (a \circ c) \otimes (b \circ d)$$

by playing with the commutative diagrams (?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hom(H,G) naturally has the structure of a group (i.e., the functor Hom(-,G) factors through the category of groups, which means that G is a group object).

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Yes, I can show that $Hom(H,G)$ is a group when $G$ is a group object, but does this help showing that two operations coincide?

Comment: I was thinking of a Yoneda's Lemma argument. But can't you just use the fact that m is a group homomorphism to get Eckmann-Hilton going.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Do you think we need any extra conditions on $m$? It's really hard for me to see any relationship between $m$ and $\circ$

Comment: No. $m$ is a morphism from the product group $G\times G$ (which can be shown to have the operation $(g,h)(k,l)=(g\circ k,h\circ l)$) to $G$ in the category of groups, and thus is a group homomorphism. By definition $$m(g\circ k,h\circ l)=m((g,h)(k,l)) = m(g,h)\circ m(k,l)$$ On the left it is $(g\circ k)\otimes (h\circ l)$, on the right it is $(g\otimes h)\circ (k\otimes l)$.